# IE11 - Infinite $digest loop in angular js with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I dont know, what to do..i tried everything,what i found on the net and spent a lot od time with it.. The app based on AngularJs uses for routing ui-router. There are tabs, that are opened from parent window programically. It works all fine, but now to the problem.If i copy the URL of new opened window and open new tab with this URL, it works fine,but when i take the same URL and paste it to parent window adreess line and press enter, then nothing happend in IE11 (digest loop in console). The strange is,that sometimes on first enter press it works, but never more than one. The $state is changing (page title change correctly), but page is not rerendered.

I tried $location.path, .hasPrefix ('!'), .html5Mode (true) ..and many others... It is still same...

Then i tried debug angular. It is looping on $locationWatch with different oldUrl and $locarion.url().

I dont know if it is important, but i got feel,that $browser.url () return different results in (ie9,ie10,FF,Chrome) and ie11. I think, it can cause the problem, but i am not na expert on ui router in angular...

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bug in angular, because official samples make same invalid behaviour.I am closing this thread now.